# Filtering/Searching fields with enumerated data (e.g. Smart Map) in an ElementCriteria model

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, filter, plugin-smartmap

I have an ElementCriteriaModel in which I need to find elements that contain a particular value for "state", which is a property of a "Smart Map" field (`$element->smartMapField->state`).

Filtering after a `find` would be easy, but I need to do this in the ElementCriteriaModel, as I am passing it to the 'criteria' option for ElementAPI (https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As of Smart Map 2.3.0, this is now possible!

> https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/filtering-entries-by-subfield-value/

---

**ORIGINAL**

<s>Currently, this isn't possible. However, it's a popular feature request which is rising quickly on the priority list.</s>

The current workaround (as you noted) is to simply filter the results afterward.